# Access permission sp_configure and reconfigure statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to enable `xp_cmdshell` on SQL Server by using this query:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1'
RECONFIGURE
```

But I'm getting error like this:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 105 [Batch Start Line 0]
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.
Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 [Batch Start Line 4]
The configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.
Msg 5812, Level 14, State 1, Line 6
You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The errors is very clear "User does not have permission to perform this action." - fix this by assigning your user the correct roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [permissions hierarchy poster](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster):

[image]

The execution of `sp_configure` and `RECONFIGURE` is granted by the `ALTER SETTINGS` permission. And from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reconfigure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles implicitly hold this permission.

So, you need to [GRANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this permission to your user or to make it member of `sysadmin` or `serveradmin` roles.